# Keep Gnuplot window open when building from Sublime Text

Tags: gnuplot, sublimetext3

I am using the gnuplot package from PackageControl in Sublime Text 3 on Windows. My gnuplot code successfully builds when run from Sublime Text, but if using a terminal that outputs the plot to a graphics window (such as the default wxt), the window appears and closes immediately.

Presumably there is a way to edit the gnuplot.sublime-build file to keep the plot window from closing, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

My Sublime Text build file for gnuplot currently looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gnuplot", "$file"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.gnuplot",

    "variants": [
        {
            "cmd": ["start", "gnuplot", "-persist", "$file"],
            "shell": true
         }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, the `-persist` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well...  I ended up just adding:

`pause -1`

To the end of my script.